# Limit the rows if same id repeats

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like below

```
ID   |   s_id   |   mark
-----------------------
1    |   2      |   10
2    |   5      |   9
3    |   7      |   8
4    |   2      |   8
5    |   2      |   10
6    |   5      |   7
7    |   3      |   7
8    |   2      |   9
9    |   5      |   8
```

I need to get SQL query for output like:-
mark column need to be in descending order.
Same s_id should not repeat more than 2 times
if same s_id repeats more than 2 times, ignore the 3rd result

```
ID   |   s_id   |   mark
-----------------------
1    |   2      |   10
2    |   2      |   9
3    |   3      |   7
4    |   5      |   9
5    |   5      |   8
6    |   7      |   8
```

Comment: This would be much easier to achieve outside of the SQL statement, in the following script/program logic that outputs/handles this data ...

Comment: @Strawberry I went with the title, maybe I'm wrong, or maybe they tagged with MySQL because it's a more popular tag, and therefore easier to get "help."

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, you can just use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a row number to each `s_id` group based on a descending order of the `mark` column.  Then, retain only those records where this row number is 1 or 2.

```
SELECT
    t.ID, t.s_id, t.mark
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, s_id, mark, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s_id ORDER BY mark DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
ORDER BY t.s_id;
```

Note: You'll notice that the record `(s_id, mark) = (2, 10)` appears twice in my result set.  Based on your input data, this is what is generated.  If you really intended to also remove duplicate `(s_id, mark)` pairs, then let us know and a small correction can be added to the query.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: @kastriotcunaku If you look closely at the OP's expected output, there is a rabbit.  A record which I would expect isn't present, and I'm not sure why.  Maybe the OP can give feedback here.

Comment: @ArshadAmeen Can you mark this answer correct if it helped you?  Or is upvote possible?

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s_id 
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN,ID,s_id,mark
         FROM   aaa)
select RN,ID,s_id,mark FROM cte
WHERE  RN <= 2
order by s_id,mark desc;
```